# How to deal with SAML Responses without a Content-Type header

Tags: http, single-sign-on, saml, saas

I maintain a web site that provides a software-as-a-service (SaaS) to many large corporates. To enable employees of those corporates to log in with their company credentials, my website implements SSO, acting as a Service Provider (SP).

I found that my Assertion Consumer Service receives quite a few SAML Responses that have no Content-Type header. Normally the header is there though. The issue happens with SAML response from a number of our customers.

At the moment, the site responds to these SAML responses with a 500 error.

I am wondering
1) what causes the absence of the Content-Type header;
2) if there is a better way to deal with this situation.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What content type are you expecting? Is it possible that they're trying to use [Redirects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0#SP_Redirect_Artifact;_IdP_Redirect_Artifact) to the ACS?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am expecting content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded, and that in the body of the request is a form with a field SAMLResponse (which I expect to contain the SAML response encoded in base64).

Comment: Well, like I linked to, there are various *different* ways for the exchange to happen - have you confirmed it's not attempting one of those other ways to complete the exchange?

Comment: I am looking at amazon SAML response, it seems they are using `text/html;charset=UTF-8` as Content-Type header. I don't think it really matters as not specified in the SAML 2.0 spec. No?